# PHP - collect data from paginated API results (in XML)

Tags: php, xml, api, hyperlink

I'm accessing data from an API supplying XML using PHP, with a retrieval format and URL like this:

```
$response = $oauth->get('https://example.com/Main/1');
```

In this case the "**1**" is the page number. It will return the first 100 results. (That I have all working.)

But if there are more results, I can't access them automatically currently. (I'd have to change the url manually.)

The returned XML will list a `<Links><rel>last</rel><href>https://example.com/Main/3</href></Links>` of how many pages there are. (In this case, **3** pages available.)

Here's a sample of the XML returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Fleet xmlns="http://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3" version="2" snapshotTime="2020-01-13T20:12:55.224Z">
  <Links>
    <rel>self</rel>
    <href>https://example.com/Main/1</href>
  </Links>
  <Links>
    <rel>last</rel>
    <href>https://example.com/Main/3</href>
  </Links>
  <Equipment>
    <EquipmentHeader>
      <OEMName>CAT</OEMName>
      <Model>D6</Model>
      <EquipmentID>1111111</EquipmentID>
      <SerialNumber>1111111</SerialNumber>
      <PIN>1111111</PIN>
    </EquipmentHeader>
    <CumulativeOperatingHours datetime="2018-07-29T18:15:30.000Z">
      <Hour>1111</Hour>
    </CumulativeOperatingHours>
  </Equipment>
  // ... and so on - 100 results...
</Fleet>
```

Is there a simple way to check the value given of the last page, and then loop through retrieving data from each of the pages (from the first to the last)?

(Since I won't know how many pages there are until the first request results are returned.)

**UPDATE**
I've come up with this for finding the number of pages:

```
$total_pages = NULL;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
// Get used name space, and use that
$namespaces = $xml->getDocNamespaces();
if(isset($namespaces[''])) {
    $defaultNamespaceUrl = $namespaces[''];
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('default', $defaultNamespaceUrl);
    $nsprefix = 'default:';
} else {$nsprefix = '';}
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//'.$nsprefix.'Links');
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    if($node->rel == 'last'){
        $last_page_url = $node->href;
        $pos = strrpos($last_page_url, '/'); // position of last slash in url
        $total_pages = $pos === false ? 0 : substr($last_page_url, $pos + 1); // if slash doesn't exist, then 0, otherwise the value after the last slash
    } // end if
} // end foreach
echo $total_pages;
```

So now I need to figure out how to loop through the requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could simplify the last page lookup, using [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$domDocument = new \DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($response);

$xpath = new \DOMXPath($domDocument);
$xpath->registerNamespace('d', 'http://standards.iso.org/iso/15143/-3');
$lastPageHref = $xpath->evaluate('string(//d:Links/d:rel[text()="last"]/following-sibling::d:href)');
$lastPage = (int)basename($lastPageHref);
```

This gets a `href` element which is the direct following sibling of a `rel` element whose text content is `"Last"`, which is itself a child of a `Links` element anywhere in the doc.

It then uses [`basename`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to get the last part of that URL, and converts it to an integer.

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/urfU3**

From there, you can simply do something like this (where `OAuthClass` is to be replaced by what class `$oauth` is of):

```
function fetchPage(YourOAuthClass $oauth, int $page): \DOMDocument 
{
  $xml = $oauth->get("https://example.com/Main/$page");

  $domDocument = new \DOMDocument();
  $domDocument->loadXML($xml);

  return $domDocument;
}

$domDocument = fetchPage($oauth, 1);

// Here, do the code above to grab $lastPage
// Also do stuff with $domDocument (handle page 1)

for ($page = 2; $page <= $lastPage; $page++) {
  $domDocument = fetchPage($oauth, $page);

  // Do stuff with $domDocument (handle current page)
}
```